# Rollup & react-md-editor: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rollup, rollupjs, react-md-editor

### Summarize the problem:

Using the library `@uiw/react-md-editor` causes `rollup` to build with error. The error happens in a, seemingly, unrelated file. Either the code editor or the button component throw this error. Neither of them have an import for `@uiw/react-md-editor`.:

```
[!] RollupError: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
src/components/Button/Button.tsx (16:60)
14: import { SourceFile } from '../../models'
15: 
16: export const Button = forwardRef<ButtonRefProps, ButtonProps>(
                                                                ^
17:     (
18:         {
```

Even importing the library without doing anything else causes this error.

```js
// RandomNewFile.ts
// Causes Error
import MDEditor from '@uiw/react-md-editor';
```

```js
// RandomNewFile.ts
// Builds successfully
// import MDEditor from '@uiw/react-md-editor';
```

### Descripbe what you've tried

1. Found a working version of `@uiw/react-md-editor`. The current version is `2.24.1` and this problem started occuring at `2.5.0`. Using the older version is not a problem.
2. Checked differences in `package.json` between version `2.5.0` and `2.6.0` but I couldn't find any significant differences.
3. Removed `--bundleConfigAsCjs` flag from `rollup -c --bundleConfigAsCjs`
4. Various tweaks to `rollup` config and `typescript` config.

### Show some code

```js
//rollup.config.js
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';

const packageJson = require('./package.json');

export default [
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.main,
        format: 'cjs',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: 'esm',
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' }),
      postcss(),
    ],
  },
  {
    input: 'dist/esm/types/index.d.ts',
    output: [{ file: 'dist/index.d.ts', format: 'esm' }],
    plugins: [dts.default()],
    external: [/\.css$/, 'react-dom'],
  },
];
```

```js
// tsconfig.js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true
  }
}
```

```json
//package.json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build": "rollup -c --bundleConfigAsCjs",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.22.20",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.22.15",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.22.15",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.2.0",
    "@monaco-editor/react": "4.5.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "25.0.4",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "15.2.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "11.1.3",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "7.4.2",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "7.4.2",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "7.4.2",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "1.0.8",
    "@storybook/addon-styling": "1.3.7",
    "@storybook/blocks": "7.4.2",
    "@storybook/react": "7.4.2",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "7.4.2",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "0.2.1",
    "@types/katex": "^0.16.5",
    "@types/react": "18.2.22",
    "@uiw/react-md-editor": "^3.24.1",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "clsx": "2.0.0",
    "katex": "^0.16.9",
    "monaco-editor": "0.43.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.30",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "rehype-sanitize": "^6.0.0",
    "rollup": "3.29.2",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "6.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "4.0.2",
    "storybook": "7.4.2",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "tslib": "2.6.2",
    "typescript": "5.2.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0"
  },
  "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
  "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts"
}
```